# Oracle Database connection in play framework 2.5.10

Tags: playframework-2.5

I am unable to connect the oracle database in play framework.
    Steps I followed as below:
    configuration of database in  application.conf file as below:
            default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
            default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
            default.username=username
            default.password=password
            ->added ojdbc14.jar in lib folder in the project
    while hitting the browser with url http://localhost:9000
    I am getting below error:
            Cannot connect to database [default]
    exception is as below on console:

```
        [error] c.z.h.p.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z)
        [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
        [error] c.z.h.p.PoolBase - HikariPool-2 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z)
        [error] application -

        ! @738nhifg4 - Internal server error, for (GET)

        play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
                at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
                at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
                at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
                at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
                at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
                at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Failed to initialize pool: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z]
                at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
                at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
                at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
        Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
                at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
                at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
                at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
        Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:400)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:375)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:346)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:105)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.appl`enter code here`y(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
                at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
                at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)


     any advice will be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the problem is Oracle connectivity with `ojdbc14.jar` is not supported by `Play Framework`.

I tried with `ojdbc6` for Oracle 11g and it worked.